# Laravel 5 Select all records if a user is admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How I get all records if a user is admin, if not is admin return only the user posts. I already try

```
Where('idUser',"=",$IdCurrentUser)->orWhere('Administrador','=','Administrador')->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know if the user is an administrator? Is it because they have a `name` set as `Administrador`?

Comment: Which user?
You mean the logged in user?

Comment: What is in `$enum`?

Comment: The logged user, if as role administrator show the records of all user, if is a normal user show only they own records

Comment: $enum is the id of the current user, i update the post to remove some confused code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you how to check `user is not an admin` part, most likely with Auth::user(), but the point is that you apply `$query->where` inside main `where` only if current user in not an admin

```
->where(function($query) use ($IdCurrentUser) {
    if (/* user is not an admin */) {
        $query->where('idUser',"=",$IdCurrentUse);
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: How i use this solution? i try          ` $post=Post::Where(function($query) use ($IdCurrentUser) {
    if (/* user is not an admin */) {
        $query->where('idUser',"=",$IdCurrentUse);
    }
})->get();` but i get a error

Comment: You should specify the if() condition yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to return the authenticated user, like

```
$isAdmin = false;
if (Auth::check())
{
  $user = Auth::user();
  if ($user->getName() == 'Administrador')
  {
    $isAdmin = true;
  }
}
```

then add `where` if not admin:

```
if (!$isAdmin)
{
  $postCollection->where('id', '=', $user->getId());
}
```

EDIT:

Also check [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/check-if-user-has-admin-role) as for how to use actual roles for admin checking instead of simple name comparison (which is the proper way to go).

Comment: I want in the query verifie if is admin equals to true then show all else show their one records. Using a unique query to do that

Comment: You are talking about "posts".
For me, it is unlikely that you store user IDs *AND* names in the "posts" table. If it is so, however, then - and only then - you could do it.
Otherwise need to query two times, or join the users table with the post table, that is quite inefficient for a lot of rows.

Comment: There is onother way withoput create two queries